# Integral of the sign function versus derivative of the absolute value

Tags: integration, derivatives

Asking Wolfram Alpha to integrate $ \operatorname{sgn}(x) $ gives me $ x \cdot \operatorname{sgn}(x) + C $, which is equivalent to $ \lvert x \rvert + C $, but asking it to differentiate $ \lvert x \rvert $ gives me $ \dfrac{x}{\lvert x \rvert} $, which is equal to $ \operatorname{sgn}(x) $ for all *non-zero* values of $ x $. I understand that $ \lvert x \rvert $ is not differentiable at zero, but how can it be that $ \int \operatorname{sgn}(x) \, dx = \lvert x \rvert + C $ for all real values of $ x $ but $ \dfrac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x} \lvert x \rvert \neq \operatorname{sgn}(x) $ for at $ x = 0 $? Where is my mistake?

Comment: The mistake is to believe that WA is always right... ;-) The antiderivative $x \operatorname{sgn}(x)+C$ is not valid at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) (Part 1) relates the derivative function and the integral function. From most math books or wikipedia, it states:

Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval $[ a , b ]$. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x \in [ a , b ]$, by
$$
    F ( x ) = \int_a^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t . 
$$
Then, $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[ a , b ]$, differentiable on the open interval $( a , b )$ and
$$
    F'( x ) = f ( x ) 
$$
for all $x \in ( a , b )$.

Alternatively, if $f$ is merely Riemann integrable, then $F$ is continuous on $[ a , b ]$ (but not necessarily differentiable).

---

My interpretation of this is that we only get to use the relationship between derivatives and anti-derivatives as inverse functions of each other as long as these conditions are met. That is, $F'(x) = f(x)$ *iff* $F(x) = |x| + C$ is both uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Since $|x|$ is not differentiable as you mentioned, then we cannot apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus part 1 to it. That is $F'(x)$ is not equal to $f(x)$. Or, the derivative of $|x| + C$ is not equal to $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$. The "mistake" you think you might be making is applying the FTC where it may not be applied.